# Use a 10-3 cable to supply 120v power to 2 duplex receptacles?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 10-3 cable to a double box that used to have 240v power. I want it to have 2 duplex outlets on 120v.  Can I use the 10-3 for the 2 circuits?

Comment: It is doable.  The 10 gauge not as much fun to work with and probably want/need to use a 20 or 15 amp breaker/s(double or handle tied) instead of the 30.

Comment: Is this 10/3 + ground or an old appliance cable w/o ground?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.  However the breaker must be changed to 20A.

Generally 10/3 means a 30A circuit (not always).  You can't put 15A or 20A receptacles on a 30A circuit.

Due to an exception, you can put 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit *if there are 2 or more sockets*... however, standard receptacles have 2 sockets so you're all set.

### The breaker handles must be tied.

What you are designing is a *Multi-Wire Branch Circuit" and it has certain rules.  One is either a 2-pole breaker must be used, or a listed handle-tie between two single breakers.

The breakers need to be placed so there is 240V between the live wires, but that is already the case on a 240V circuit, so just don't *move* them.

### The neutral must be pigtailed.

Another MWBC rule is that neutral must be pigtailed.  So you must use a wire-nut and 2 short white wires to distribute neutral to the 2 receptacles - *you cannot daisy chain neutral from one receptacle to the other*.  Same rules as ground, actually. (nobody will arrest you if the pigtails aren't white, but it's good style, so impresses the inspector, see NEC 110.12).

The pigtails can be #12 (presuming a 20A breaker), they don't need to be #10. That will make them easier to put on the socket.   Buy "solid core" THHN wire by the foot at better hardware stores for pennies, or shuck Romex cable to get pigtails.

### GFCI and AFCI get a little weird.

GFCI protection is best done at the receptacle.  If you want GFCI protection at the breaker, you must use a 2-pole, 240V GFCI breaker.

If you want or need AFCI protection at the breaker, it depends on what your panel manufacturer offers. Some offer 2-pole AFCI breakers. Other have advanced single-pole AFCI breakers designed to be used in MWBCs, which don't use the circuit's neutral wire.  Breaker type matters and you must use only breakers UL-Listed (or UL-Classified by a competitor) for your panel.

Answer (score 0):

Do you require these duplex outlets each be fed by their own circuit breaker, or is it acceptable for your intended use that both be powered from a single breaker? Harper's [thorough answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/242248/45928) describes the two-breaker scenario. If you don't require that though the wiring for a single breaker is somewhat simpler.

1. Connect the neutral to the receptacles. Pigtail or not; it doesn't matter when MWBC is not involved (but still I'd do pigtails if for no other reason than attaching 10 gauge to the receptacles will be difficult).
2. Choose one of the hot wires and connect it to the receptacles as well.
3. Insulate the other hot wire - for example, cap it with a twist-on connector.
4. Install the appropriate single-pole breaker in the panel: conventional, GFCI, AFCI/combo, etc.
5. Cap the end of the unused conductor in the panel too, and if removal of the former 30A breaker has left an open hole in the deadfront panel, fill the hole either with a blank cover plate or by installing a "spare" (ie unused) breaker into the slot.